# How to fallback to URL alias of language in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a node type with translation enabled for all fields including URL alias.

```
mysql> select * from url_alias where source='/node/22';
+-----+----------+----------------------+----------+
| pid | source   | alias                | langcode |
+-----+----------+----------------------+----------+
|  21 | /node/22 | /foo/bar             | en       |
|  45 | /node/22 | /bar/baz             | fr       |
+-----+----------+----------------------+----------+
```

I have language prefix as negotiation method.

When I access this node in /en/foo/bar, can see english version. But when I change the URL to fr/foo/bar, I get page not found. I would like to redirect to fr/bar/baz this case.

Is there out of box solution to get this functionality?